# How to change password of a newly created user using variable in postgresql 9.5 SP

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

I have created a stored procedure (function) for my postgresql 9.5 database to create users. code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_user (name text, cred text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  name text := 'abc123';
BEGIN
  CREATE USER name WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB 
  NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
  GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO name;
  GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test_schema TO name;
  GRANT SELECT ON test_schema.test_table TO name;
  ALTER USER name WITH PASSWORD cred;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This fails for altering password for the user. The moment I replace "cred" with hardcoded password, it works.

So,  ALTER USER name WITH PASSWORD 'userpassword' works,
but NOT with any variable (cred).

Is there anyway we can use variable instead of hard coding the password?

Tried running another function, just for password

Answer (score 0):

You must execute the ALTER USER with dynamic SQL, for example:

```
EXECUTE 'ALTER USER || name || ' WITH PASSWORD '|| cred;
```

I believe that you must execute dynamic SQL in whole code of CREATE and GRANT commands, because I think always will create the user called "name"

Comment: Thanks much! But, one issue. Although it says query executed successfully, I can not login using this user's id and pswd. Below is what I'm using:BEGIN
      CREATE USER name WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
      EXECUTE 'ALTER USER || name ||  WITH PASSWORD '|| cred;
      GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO name;
      GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test_schema TO name;
      GRANT SELECT ON test_schema.test TO name;
   END;

Answer (score 0):

it does not work because the user is called "name", it does not take parameter value

As I mentioned before, you must do it dynamically all the code to create and grant

the function should look like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION add_user (name text, cred text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
 name_temp text := 'abc123';
BEGIN
EXECUTE ' CREATE USER '|| $1 ||' WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB    NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION';
EXECUTE ' GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO ' || $1;
EXECUTE ' GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA test_schema TO '|| $1;
EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON test_schema.test_table TO '||  $1;
EXECUTE 'ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD '''|| $2||'''';
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I recommend using the format function to form the texts of CREATE, GRANT and ALTER, for safety issues, example:

EXECUTE format(' GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test TO %I ', $1);

other point, consider variable name diferent of parameter name

thist function work for me