# Update PostgreSQL user credentials using variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to update user credentials for PostgreSQL db user using Python. I've tried referring to the following thread but that doesn't seem to solve my issue unfortunately:

[How to change password of a newly created user using variable in postgresql 9.5 SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978968/how-to-change-password-of-a-newly-created-user-using-variable-in-postgresql-9-5)

Here's my code:

```
con = p.connect(database="mydB", user="abc", password="testing", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()

uid = "adi"
pwd = "test6"

statement = statement = '''CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION add_user ({}, {}) RETURNS void AS $$ EXECUTE ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD || $2||'''.format(uid,pwd)

cur.execute( statement)
cur.execute('''COMMIT''')
```

I get the following error:
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'adi'"

Please help or refer me to a thread with a better solution. Thanks in advance, everyone!

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5thC.png)

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. edited the question with the complete error!

Comment: Your traceback differs from the code. Please post the code that leads to that error.

Comment: @KlausD., added the original code - edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: @KlausD. I have added my answer here. I was able to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this successfully.

```
import psycopg2 as p
con = p.connect(database="mydB", user="adi", password="xxxx", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
cur = con.cursor()

uid = "adi"
pwd = "test"

statement = '''ALTER USER {} WITH PASSWORD %s '''.format(uid)

cur.execute(statement, [pwd])
cur.execute('''COMMIT''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the username and password in the actual statement and try executing.

First try removing the extra quotation before `ALTER USER` and execute.
If doesn't work try this:

```
statement = '''CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION add_user ({}, {}) RETURNS void AS $$ EXECUTE 'ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD || $2||'''.format(uid,pwd)

cur.execute(statement)
```

Comment: Tried the following:                                                                                                statement = '''CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION add_user ({}, {}) RETURNS void AS $$ EXECUTE ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD || $2||'''.format(uid,pwd)                      I get the error: ProgrammingError: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ EXECUTE ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD || $2||"