# Function to dynamically change postgres password

Tags: postgresql, function, settings, alter

I'm trying to create a function that dynamically changes the password for a client but I get an error "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="  ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD = '$1';"

How do I fix this? Thank you for your time

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."Change_password"(
    password character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
   ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD= '$1';

END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."Change_password"(character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
    
    SELECT public."Change_password"(
    '10'
)
```

Comment: PASSWORD=  THE equal SIGN is WRONG!!!! BEWARE

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the trivial syntax error of the superfluous `=`, you cannot use a parameter in an `ALTER` statement. You will have to use dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE format(
           'ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD %L',
           $1
        );
```

Let me add that changing a superuser's password from an application like that does not look like a sane security concept. You are not running your application with a database superuser, are you?

Comment: I'm running a localhost server for a client and I wanted the client to easily change the password if need be.

Answer (score 0):

A plain syntax error, according to [ALTER USER documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-alteruser.html):  there is no `=` after `PASSWORD`
it should be: `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '$1';`

EDIT:
After looking into problem deeper, it seems that whole statement must be run dynamically.
Check the answers to similar question: [How to change user password in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978968/how-to-change-password-of-a-newly-created-user-using-variable-in-postgresql-9-5)

Comment: This is not correct for my version. It's setting the password to $1

Comment: Well so the error does not appear anymore and code works. If you want it to be changed dynamically just replace ‘$1’ with ‘password’ parameter

Comment: That doesn't work either, it sets the password to string "password" without quotes. Changing the input parameter to something else like pass doesn't work either.

Comment: ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD password; - is that what you have tried ?

Comment: It throws syntax error.